# Why mod_rewrite isn't working in this case?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have created .htaccess in /var/www/html, I have only .html pages here and rewrite is working just fine, I have also created same .htaccess file in /var/www/html/tree, here I have .php files and the rewrite isn't working.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

000-default.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /var/www/html>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/tree>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Thing I expect to see:

https://example.com/index.html --> https://example.com/index

https://example.com/tree/wallet.php --> https://example.com/tree/wallet

Comment: When debugging rewrite rules, we need sample source URLs along with what you expect them to be transformed in to.

Comment: `rm /var/www/html/tree/.htaccess`

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thank you, now it is "removing" the .php but since that, every request = 404. I wanted to display all the content, just remove the extension.

Comment: I just want to be clear because you are saying “remove”, which is something that I could interpret multiple ways in this context. 1) You want Apache to 30x redirect users from `/tree/file.php` to `/tree/file`. 2) You want to publish “friendly” URLs such as `/tree/file` and have Apache load `/tree/file.php`. Questions similar to this get asked often, so I’m trying to clarify, especially because #2 is a two-step process, half of which Apache cannot do, you must do it instead.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, thanks for that. What I am looking for is user will go to tree/file, file.php will load BUT only tree/file will be displayed in URL.

Comment: Child directories should inherit from their parent, so unless you really need to do something different, try to keep the config in one place, both htaccess and the server. If you have a single folder of `tree`, be literal and put that directly into the rule. Conditions stop at the first rule found, they need to be redone for the next rule. You probably want `[L]` in that directory rule. I’m personally steering people towards router scripts, effectively send all 404s (from Apache’s perspective) to a file, and then use PHP to determine what to do next